# Use of article: "by the air" or "by air"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

> I like to travel by the air.
>
> I like to travel by air.

I think the first one is correct because no human can travel in air (general meaning of 2nd one). When "the" is used with air it means by travelling by some "means" but the correct answer is the 2nd one.
Why is that?

Comment: The definite article is not used in the structure: "travel by" e.g *They travelled **by road** / **land** / **sea** / **air*** and *I go to work by bike/car/bus/tram/train*.

Comment: *I think the first one is correct because no human can travel in air ... .* This is your mistake. **By** usually introduces at least one of the means that are *utilised* to achieve the verbal action. The essence of flying is that there is a gas present (usually, air) - you cannot fly in a vacuum. Air (uncountable) is therefore used in the achievement of flight.

Comment: Similar: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579555/year-followed-year-phrase-and-missing-a-article/579576#579576

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *by air* is actually an idiom, meaning "by flying in airplanes", so the correct usage is without "the."

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by%20air