# "Year followed year" phrase, and missing 'a' article

Tags: grammar, articles

Maybe some of you will know, why isn't there any article 'a' before the nouns 'year' in the phrase "year followed year"?

This phenomenon is also present in phrases like "year after year", "month after month", "day in, day out" etc.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The general guidance (not “a rule”) for students is that all singular, countable nouns must be qualified by a determiner or quantifier – **the** cat, **a** month, **any** apple, **one** car, **my** ball, **that** house, etc.

That guidance is not valid for all functions of a noun – in many cases the noun becomes **uncountable** and is used to describe a particular example of that noun.

In this case, the guidance is:

**If the noun is part of a prepositional phrase**, we have

When I was **in college** / He was **at home** / They sent him **to prison** / we did it **in bed** / I saw it **on television** / **By day**, he was a policeman; **by night** he was a burglar / He went to town by bus.

And we have a double expression – {X preposition X} – which creates an adverbial or adjectival phrase.

**Arm in arm**, they walked along the road. / They were **side by side** / **Year after year**, she grew more beautiful.

**If a noun is the name of a general institution**, we have

He left **college/prison/hospital/home**. **College/prison/hospital/home** is where he ended his days.

There are also some expression of the form {X coordination conjunction Y} in which X and Y form a natural pair – They are **husband and wife**. / **Pen and paper** to hand, I started the letter.

**If a noun is used to designate one from a class of previously mentioned objects**, we have

I had to look after a dog, a cat and a parrot. I left them alone for a moment and, when I came back, **dog, cat and parrot** were chasing each other around the room.

In your case, we have "Year following year, he waited for the ship to return."

**Year following year** = "Each year that followed the previous year" and the whole clause is adverbial.

As it is adverbial, the noun(s) are uncountable.

Comment: +1 ! Very informative !!

Comment: Have you a reference work that this came from, please? It would be good to know how comprehensive this list is. Also, 'adverbial usages' seems to constitute a fourth category. / The categories vary between being semantically and syntactically defined.

Answer (score 0):

In English, there is the Concept of "Zero Article", along with the well-known articles "the", "a" and "an", which are used to refer to nouns.

While "the" goes with Definite nouns, "a" and "an" go with general, non-specific nouns.

The "Zero Article" or "Zero Determiner" is used when (in general) it is even more non-specific.

Consider these three cases:

(1) It was the hottest year of the Eighteenth Century when the Queen was ill [[ very specific, because there is only one "hottest" year ]]

(2) It was a very hot year when the Queen was ill [[ non-specific, because there are many "very hot" years ]]

(3) While year followed year, the Queen was continuously ill, showing no signs of recovery [[ very non-specific, because there are many years over which the Queen was ill ]]

There are many online references to "Zero Article" or "Zero Determiner" ; Here are two :

https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-article-grammar-1692619
https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/determiners-zero-article.htm

Comment: Master has argued cogently that two 'invisible' articles are idiomatic in English, the 'zero article' being the least definite (We're having chicken for tea /  We're having a chicken for tea) and the 'null article' being the most definite (Ford became the President of the USA in 1974 / Ford became President of the USA in 1974).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth . your comment. while making sense. is also cryptic ! Who is the "master" ? I guess "greybeard" ? That cogent answer makes no mention of "Zero Article" and "Null Article". I am confused, Request clarification !

Comment: Peter Master (qv); an in-house search for 'null article' should take you there, if his name doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

Year is a plural (or countable) noun, in the sense that it is a noun that can take a plural form (as opposed to a mass noun e.g. sugar), but in this case the reference is indefinite since you are not referring to a defined period of time (e.g. a year i.e. one year), so the zero article is used (no article).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm sorry but how is 'year' a plural noun when we have "the diploma course takes one _year_" but "the degree course takes three _years_"?